# Why function hide/show element not work , when cover with tag form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why function hide/show element not work , when cover with tag form ?

When i  test check radio button for hide/show elements , it's not work.

But when i remove `tag form` , and test it's OK

How to using this function hide/show elements with `tag form`

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3n0Le1c/1/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" id="buy_out_form-id" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);" style=" margin: 0px; ">
<script>
// script for hide.show element base on radio button //
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".color").click(function(){
       if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
           $("#red").show();
           $("#blue").hide();  

       }
       if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
           $("#blue").show();
           $("#red").hide();  
       }
   });
});
</script>
<input onchange="this.form.submit();" class="color" type="radio" name="rdSpace" value="red" checked="">RED
<br>
<input onchange="this.form.submit();" class="color" type="radio" name="rdSpace" value="blue">BLUE
<br>
<span id="red">RED RED RED RED RED</span>
<span id="blue" style="display: none;">BLUE BLUE BLUE BLUE BLUE</span>
</form>
```

Comment: because you are submitting form on radio button change which is causing form to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the HTML input tagto

```
<input onchange="javascript:e.preventDefault();
this.form.submit();" class="color" type="radio" name="rdSpace" value="red" checked="">RED
<br>
<input onchange="javascript:e.preventDefault();this.form.submit();" class="color" type="radio" name="rdSpace" value="blue">Blue
```

This will avoid your form from submitting.

**EDIT:**
If you want the form to submit and just the `hide`/`show` to work fine , you need to move the red/blue span out of the from and use ajax to submit the form so that the form submits but the span with red/blue are maintained on the page.

Comment: no explanation of the error or issue, just plain jane code...assume i did -1 :)

Comment: @NoobEditor Well you have explained the issue clear in your answer so that helps others,also you  made changes in my edit to make it be better and correct so i cant say no to you for doing so sir  :) .

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".color").click(function (e) {
         if ($(this).attr("value") == "red") {
             $("#red").show();
             $("#blue").hide();

         }
         if ($(this).attr("value") == "blue") {
             $("#blue").show();
             $("#red").hide();
         }
         e.preventDefault();
     });
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d3n0Le1c/2/)

Comment: The demo does not work .That is because we need to have the e.PreventDefault()  to be the first statement in  click callback.The code you have written does the same thing as the fiddle provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

okay...so lets break down to understand what is happening :

These 2 input lines here :

```
<input onchange="this.form.submit();" class="color" type="radio" name="rdSpace" value="red" checked="">RED

<input onchange="this.form.submit();" class="color" type="radio" name="rdSpace" value="blue">BLUE
```

you have set `onchange` event to `this.form.submit();`.

So when ever the value of the `radio` will change, this will try to `submit` the form as mentioned through `this.form.submit();`

On clicking any of the radio buttons, jQuery is detecting the event and is bubbling the action needed (`show();` / `hide();` ) but on completion the control goes back to `onchange` and tries to `submit` the `form` its wrapped in - *and hence your error*

What i would suggest is that you add a `submit` button rather than firing an event as it causing the issue or you can use `javascript:e.preventDefault()` as mentioned in the other answer!

Comment: ya, if the form is not need to be submitted on change i think your suggestion of adding a button for submit separately is much simpler and better way.